# Using geopy with password authenticated proxy

Tags: python, authentication, proxy, geopy

I'm trying to use geopy with a set of coordinates and everything works fine at first.

```
from geopy.geocoders import GoogleV3
# some coordinates as example
latitude, longitude = 24.47646, 85.3095
geolocator = GoogleV3()
location = geolocator.geocode('%s, %s' (latitude, longitude))
address = location.address
print address
# this would print something like 
Unnamed Road, Burhia Ahri, Jharkand 825406, India
```

The enviroment I'm working on requires an authenticated proxy,
for example purposes let's say something like

```
proxy_address = 'http://proxy.tests.mydomain'
proxy_port = 3128
proxy_user = 'my_user'
proxy_pass = 'my_pass'
```

Asuming the requirement of authenticated proxy to make it work, I've looked at geopy [github page](https://github.com/geopy/geopy) and [the docs](http://geopy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and even if proxies are mentioned, not a single valid url is found.

It seems like sending a dictionary with the 'proxies' parameter is supported, but there is no user/password authenticated variant mentioned anywhere.

Is there any way that something like this is doable?

```
geolocator = GoogleV3(proxies={'http': proxy_address,
                               'password': my_user + my_pass})
```

Edit: Spelling

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For those who may encounter the same problem, I've found a solution to my problem that involves playing with the os module.

```
import os
def set_proxy():
    proxy_addr = 'http://{user}:{passwd}@{address}:{port}'.format(
        user='user_example', passwd='pass_example', 
        address='address_example', port=int('port_example'))
    os.environ['http_proxy'] = proxy_addr
    os.environ['https_proxy'] = proxy_addr

def unset_proxy():
    os.environ.pop('http_proxy')
    os.environ.pop('https_proxy')

set_proxy()
geolocator = GoogleV3()
location = geolocator.geocode('%s, %s' % (latitude, longitude), timeout=10)
address = location.address
unset_proxy()
```

Comment: still i got timeout error, any other way ?

Comment: After setting the timeout it worked, thanks !