# geocoder Service error in python

Tags: proxy, python-3.5, google-geocoder, geopy

I am having a service error as I am trying to run geocoders from geopy to get a location coordinates in python.I have set my proxy config, given it an api_key.
Im not sure why I am getting this error. From the search that I have done on this, it seems that this might be a proxy issue but I have that set up already.
What could be the problem here?

This is my code :

```
from geopy import geocoders

proxies={'http': 'http://location:port', 'https': 'http://localhost:port'}
api_key = '.......'

g = geocoders.GoogleV3(api_key=api_key,proxies=proxies, timeout=10)

location = 'Mountain View, CA'
try:
    place, (lat, lng) = g.geocode(location)
except ValueError as error_message:
    print("Error: geocode failed on input %s with message %s" % (location, error_message))
```

this is my error output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/aqm1152/anaconda/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 1254, in do_open
    h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers)
  File "/Users/aqm1152/anaconda/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 1106, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
  File "/Users/aqm1152/anaconda/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 1151, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body)
  File "/Users/aqm1152/anaconda/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 1102, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)
  File "/Users/aqm1152/anaconda/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 934, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/Users/aqm1152/anaconda/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 877, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/Users/aqm1152/anaconda/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 1260, in connect
    server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "/Users/aqm1152/anaconda/lib/python3.5/ssl.py", line 377, in wrap_socket
    _context=self)
  File "/Users/aqm1152/anaconda/lib/python3.5/ssl.py", line 752, in __init__
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/Users/aqm1152/anaconda/lib/python3.5/ssl.py", line 988, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
  File "/Users/aqm1152/anaconda/lib/python3.5/ssl.py", line 633, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLEOFError: EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:645)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/aqm1152/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/geopy/geocoders/base.py", line 143, in _call_geocoder
    page = requester(req, timeout=(timeout or self.timeout), **kwargs)
  File "/Users/aqm1152/anaconda/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 163, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/Users/aqm1152/anaconda/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 466, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/Users/aqm1152/anaconda/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 484, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/Users/aqm1152/anaconda/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 444, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/Users/aqm1152/anaconda/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 1297, in https_open
    context=self._context, check_hostname=self._check_hostname)
  File "/Users/aqm1152/anaconda/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 1256, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:645)>

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/aqm1152/Documents/TestingCode/ACERT/test_1.py", line 12, in <module>
    place, (lat, lng) = g.geocode(location)
  File "/Users/aqm1152/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/geopy/geocoders/googlev3.py", line 217, in geocode
    self._call_geocoder(url, timeout=timeout), exactly_one
  File "/Users/aqm1152/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/geopy/geocoders/base.py", line 171, in _call_geocoder
    raise GeocoderServiceError(message)
geopy.exc.GeocoderServiceError: EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:645)
```

Answer (score 1):

I modified your code as below, as I don't use proxy and apply an API, and it works in my machine.

```
from geopy import geocoders

#proxies={'http': 'http://location:port', 'https': 'http://localhost:port'}
#api_key = '.......'

g = geocoders.GoogleV3()

location = 'Mountain View, CA'
try:
    place, (lat, lng) = g.geocode(location)
except ValueError as error_message:
    print("Error: geocode failed on input %s with message %s" % (location, error_message))

print (place, lat, lng)
```

Here is the result.

```
Mountain View, CA, USA 37.3860517 -122.0838511
```

From the trackback, it looks all the errors are related to SSL. You may try to add below code at the beginning to disable SSL Certification verification as an alternative.

```
import ssl 

# Disable SSL certificate verification
try:
    _create_unverified_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context
except AttributeError:
    # Legacy Python that doesn't verify HTTPS certificates by default
    pass
else:
    # Handle target environment that doesn't support HTTPS verification
    ssl._create_default_https_context = _create_unverified_https_context
```

I have encountered similar problem in Anaconda running Python 2.7 in a `env` with the `root` running Python 3.6. The problem wasn't encountered in Anaconda with both `root` and `env` running Python 2.7 in another machine.

In addition, [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41873599/using-geopy-with-password-authenticated-proxy) about proxy server set up for `geopy` using `os` module may be good reference.

Hope this help.